# java class to json

Tags: json, gson

can someone help me with a java class which after json serialization yealds fallowing json results:

```
{
   "cinemas":[
   { 
      "id":1,
      "name":"Aberdeen Queen's Links",
      "cinema_url":"http://www.cineworld.co.uk/cinemas/1"
   }]
}
```

Comment: What do you need to know about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want? its called hand feeding =.= you should really check some tutorials Good luck with your codes though..

```
    String text = "{\"cinemas\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Aberdeen Queen's Links\",\"cinema_url\":\"http://www.cineworld.co.uk/cinemas/1\"}]}";

    try {
        JSONObject myJSONObject = new JSONObject(text);
        //replace text with the ACTUAL json response text
        JSONArray myArray = myJSONObject.getJSONArray("cinemas");
        int id = myArray.getJSONObject(0).getInt("id");
        String name = myArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
        String cinema_url = myArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("cinema_url");
        //do what you want here
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to manipulate JSON in Java, you could use this library:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: i looked at them but they dont seem to be helpfull

Comment: Gson is much better than json! learn it if youre free. really! good comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce that structure by doing the following:

I'm assuming you're using a Cinema object of some sort that contains the id, name and Url.

I created an ArrayList of Cinema with one cinema object in it.  I then put that ArrayList into a HashMap, with the key "cinemas"

I used flexjson and did a deepSerialize on the map and got the exact structure you mentioned above.

Here's an example:
        Cinema c = new Cinema();
        c.setId(1);
        c.setName("Aberdeen Queen's Links");
        c.setCinemaUrl("http://www.cineworld.co.uk/cinemas/1");

```
    Map<String, List<Cinema>> m = new HashMap<String, List<Cinema>>();
    List<Cinema> a = new ArrayList<Cinema>();
    a.add(c);
    m.put("cinemas", a);

    System.out.println(new JSONSerializer().deepSerialize(m));
```